# sending voip push notification from one signal

Tags: swift, voip, onesignal

I want to use one signal to send `VoIP push notifications` to the iPhone. so I created a VoIP push notification and uploaded the p12 certificate to one signal dashboard in postman or curl. When I send a notification, it returns 200 (status success) but no notification is sent to my device. do you have any idea why?

request :

> curl --include \
>        --request POST \
>        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>        --data-binary "{\"app_id\" : \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4a41-ac20-363497c923e5\",
>   \"identifier\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",
>   \"language\":\"en\", \"device_type\":0,
>   \"tags\":{\"FirstName\":\"amir\",\"LastName\":\"tutunchi\",\"Speciality\":\"Yoga\",\"MeetingID\":\"456354646\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"2019-05-29T22:45:47+04:30\",\"AppointmentTitle\":\"check\"}}"\
>       https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players

response :

> {
>       "success": true,
>       "id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" }

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/voip-notifications)

Comment: yes, one signal VOIP was broken. so we switch to SNS and it works well. I hope they fix it soon

Comment: Facing same issue and I can't switch to SPS right now. Does FCM support VoIP push?